# AWS CDK Destroy - skip Retain resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

For deployed stack which have have resources marked as "removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN", cdk destroy - will try to remove these resources
AWS console CloudFormation - will give the option to destroy the stack while skipping retain rescues.
How can I accomplish this using CDK? How?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Well, after long conversation with the AWS support team, it appears that adding

```
currentVersionOptions:{
   removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN
},
```

into lambda.Function - wont add it into the CloudFromation template. Hence, one should add the following rows at the end of the Lambda creation:

```
const r = myLambdaFunction.node.defaultChild as cdk.CfnResource;
r.applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation on [`RemovalPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.RemovalPolicy.html)

> RETAIN    This uses the 'Retain' DeletionPolicy, which will cause the resource to be retained in the account, but orphaned from the stack.

In other words after you use `cdk destroy` the stack is going to be removed but resources makred with `Retain` are going to still exist in your AWS Account.

Comment: please refer to my answer

Comment: Thanks. If you can please update the question as well to include details that it's about lambda and its peculiarities with regards to CloudFormation.